# React and Angular templates missing in 'dotnet new' command

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, spa-template

In Visual Studio Code I ran

```
 dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*
```

Somehow the templates 'react', 'reactredux' and 'angular' are missing.
(They are also missing when running the above command in my Powershell window)

How come?

I have VS Code version 1.19.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed .NET Core 2.1.4 SDK and now they are available when running 'dotnet new'.